# Image Background flickers/flashes white while page loads

Tags: html, css

I am building a small website project for a class of mine and I seem to notice whenever I clink on a link on my site, the page flickers. I assume it's due to it being a fairly-sized file.

My code is as follows:

```
body {
   background: url("../img/veggiesOnWood.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

The only other thing in my stylesheet is:

```
.main {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

When I upload the image online and link the background-image to that url, the flickering issue is solved. But when I link it back to the directory on my computer, the flickering is back. I tried reading into it online but no success.

Do you guys have any thoughts or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, when you upload your site online it's the server that solves the flickering issue because I believe that server's has an impact on web performance. However this is just my opinion.